# Using WCF Contracts to operate WPF Client

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, web-services

I'm trying to give functionality to the user where they can remotely control the client on their system from a mobile device or laptop.

What I have created is a WCF Console application which holds the contracts etc. and starts the server.

Now here's the thing, if I create a HTML page I can't do anything with it to make it communicate with the server and then the client as I'll need the HTML page to make call a method on my WPF client to initiate an action.

Has anyone had any experience with this, I think almost there with my solution it's just this wall that I've hit.

Thanks

Comment: You could consume your WCF service using JavaScript or jQuery in your HTML page. Not sure what you meant by calling a method on your WPF client - how would you consume an exe's methods remotely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your looking for a way to call WCF server functions from a webpage then use Ajax enabled WCF service. Read here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33234/A-beginner-s-guide-for-consuming-a-WCF-service-in